# Oracle - Updating CLOB Column

Tags: oracle, clob

I am receiving a very strange error, not sure where in my code this is coming from and how to solve it:   ORA-22920: row containing the LOB value is not locked

Here is my code.   I've never seen that message before.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_clob (
  p_company_id       NUMBER,
  p_table_name       VARCHAR2,
  p_column_name      VARCHAR2,
  p_clob_content     CLOB) IS

v_clob_ref           CLOB;
v_amount             NUMBER;
v_offset             NUMBER;
v_length             NUMBER;
v_content            VARCHAR2(4000);
v_update             VARCHAR2(32000);
v_insert             VARCHAR2(32000);
v_select             VARCHAR2(32000);

BEGIN
  v_offset    := 1;
  v_amount    := 4000;
  v_length    := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(p_clob_content);


  /*** Reset CLOB Column Value ***/
  v_update    := '
    UPDATE ' || p_table_name || '
    SET ' || p_column_name || ' = EMPTY_CLOB()
    WHERE company_id = ' || p_company_id ;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_update;

  /*** Loop through 4k chunks of CLOB ***/
  WHILE v_offset <= v_length LOOP
    v_select := '
      SELECT ' || p_column_name || '
      FROM ' || p_table_name || '
      WHERE company_id = ' || p_company_id;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_select INTO v_clob_ref;

    v_content := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(p_clob_content, v_amount, v_offset);
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(v_clob_ref, LENGTH(v_content), v_content);
    COMMIT;

    v_offset := v_offset + v_amount;
  END LOOP;

END update_clob;
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `COMMIT` to *after* the `END LOOP`:

```
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(v_clob_ref, LENGTH(v_content), v_content);

    v_offset := v_offset + v_amount;
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END update_clob;
```

`dbms_lob` routines are not SQL calls that atomically change rows, so Oracle requires the row itself be locked while you are writing to it, and that `commit` after the `writeappend` is ending your transaction and unlocking the row before you're done with it.